# IMPORTXML To Return a Value from dividendhistory.org

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to return the value of "Yield:" from a series of stocks from a URL [dividenhistory.org](https://dividendhistory.org/), for example [HDIF](https://dividendhistory.org/payout/TSX/Hdif/) into a Google sheet using IMPORTXML, where F7 represents the user supplied ticker.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/TSX/"&F7, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[4]")
```

The problem with the above is the yield value is not always located in the same paragraph, depending on the ticker. It also returns with the word "Yield:" as part of the value.

I believe I should be using the XPATH parameter which should find and return the yield value only, but I am lost. I am open to all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with a few of the tickers there, and this should work. For example:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/ctas/", "//p[contains(.,'Yield')]/text()")
```

Output:

```
Yield: 1.05%
```

Obviously, you can change 'ctas' for any user input.

Try this and see if it works on all tickers.

EDIT:

To get only the number `1.05`, you need to split the result and output the 2nd part:

```
=index(split(IMPORTXML("https://dividendhistory.org/payout/ctas/", "//p[contains(.,'Yield')]/text()"), ": "),2)
```

Output:

```
0.0105
```

Comment: In my original post I should have been a little more clear in that I was looking to only return the numerical data as a number. From your example, I am just looking for 1.05%.

Comment: Some tickers do not work e.g. BEP.UN. Error message is "#N/A Imported content is empty." Page source for BEP.UN indicates a value of 12.05% for yield.

Comment: @BadDogTitan Not sure what you're talking about. There's no BEP.UN, there's PBF.UN, it's yield is 7.18% and it works for me. But, generally, you should expect that in one or more of the tickers this will fail, or that it will work now and will fail next month. That's the nature of scraping, I'm afraid.

Comment: BEP.UN is TSX listed, so I think that is why you are not finding it. The last sentence of your post was what I was slowly coming to - that scraping is not the most reliable. I have accepted your solution, as it fulfilled the request. Thanks, Jack.

Comment: @BadDogTitan You're welcome and, yes, good luck!